# Select count while count is greater than a specific number in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get last month records from table. I have tried:

```
SELECT count(*) as numberOfRows from Table where created_at >  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months'
```

It's Ok, but I want to add some conditions:

> If numberOfRows >= 10, do nothing (numberOfRows can be 20, 30, ...)
>
> else if numberOfRows < 10, select from this table until numberOfRows
>       = 10 (last 2 months, 3 months, etc...).

How can I do that?
Thanks in advances!

Comment: Do you or don't you want records from more than one month ago?  This is not clear to me.

Comment: Your description sounds pretty useless.  Why not just return `greatest(count(*), 10)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH curr_month_cnt AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM your_table
    WHERE created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months'
)

SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months'
UNION ALL
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM your_table
    WHERE
        created_at <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months' AND
        (SELECT cnt FROM curr_month_cnt) < 10
    ORDER BY created_at desc
    LIMIT
        GREATEST(0, 10 - (SELECT cnt FROM curr_month_cnt))
) t
```

This will return a maximum of 10 records, starting with the most recent month and going backwards.  In the event that the latest month have not 10 records, then two and three months old data would be returned, in that order.

Comment: Sorry, my description do not enough clear.
I want to get all records in latest month. If the event in latest month have not  10 records then  going backwards until get enough 10 records. Else if the event in latest month has records greater than 10 will get all of them. The number of rows is 20, 30 will ok too.

Comment: If curr_month_cnt is greater than 10, an error occurred: " LIMIT must not be negative". How can I resolve it?

Comment: @javimuu Use `GREATEST()` to limit the expression to being no smaller than zero.  This should get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you would seem to want:

```
select greatest(10, count(*)) as numberOfRows
from Table
where created_at >  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months';
```

This seems rather surprising.  Perhaps you want:

```
select (case when sum( (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months' ) :: int) >= 10 
             then sum( (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months' ) :: int)
             else least(10, count(*))
        end) as numberOfRows
from Table
where created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months';
```

Comment: Thanks you for answered my question.
An error has occurred:
```
ERROR:  cannot cast type timestamp without time zone to integer
LINE 1: ...e WHEN SUM( (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months' ) :: int) >=... 
```
What should I do?